# Directory.Exists not working in wix installer custom action

Tags: c#, wix

I have a customaction for wix installer where in I am checking whether a directory exists. Though the directory exists, the if condition is resolving to false. The strange thing is same snippet works in console application. Here is the code.

```
string msOnline = Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "WindowsPowerShell", "v1.0", "Modules", "MSOnline");
  session.Log(msOnline); //'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MSOnline'.
  if (Directory.Exists(msOnline))
  {
      session.Log("MSOnline module is installed");
      session["AZURE_MODULE"] = "Installed";
  }
```

Not being able to get my head around as to why is this not working when same code works in console app.

Comment: Can this be a permission problem? When you run the same code from the console, you are most likely doing this as administrator. However, the installer might not run elevated and it simply cannot access that location...

Comment: @YanSklyarenko, it's exactly the opposite. I ran console in non admin mode and ran installer in both elevated and non elevated mode.

Comment: May be this is 32/64 bit process issue as mentioned in this msdn forum link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c54f8368-035e-478e-b988-b180a3c7e3da/file-not-found-for-existing-file-in-system32-directory?forum=csharpgeneral
May be you are running console app as 64 bit and setup as 32 bit or vice-versa.